# How to install Ubuntu on a Chromebook with 16 gb internal storage?

Tags: updates, versions, chromebook

I want to install Ubuntu in my chromebook (Dell Chromebook 11 3120) but I don't known which version will work properly due to its limited internal storage (The [Ubuntu system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) says that at least 25 GB of storage is required).

The specification is 16GB eMMc, with 4GB DDR4 RAM and Intel Celeron N2840 processor (1.83 GHz).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407) and [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/986878/).

Comment: I would very much consider what apps you'll run in deciding; as the different *light* flavors can perform differently depending on which apps you'll use.. Your question deals only with the hardware side of the question (ie. part only). Also consider how long you want to use it (ie. support duration; fastest may not be great if it's only got 1 month of support left as some do for example - consider everything, not just hardware).

Comment: @ Everyone who close voted, please reconsider if this question is still a duplicate after the recent edits.

Comment: I'll provide more of my 2c worth.. What the minimal requirements are will vary specifically with what you do with it. If you have less disk space allocated; you need to be more regular in applying security fixes/updates (*so they don't accrue which will require more free space as more to download & install; and space is only reclaimed after that is done*). A recent review of a Lubuntu *noble* install states "*The minimal install only takes 4 GB of disk space, and its lightning fast. It only uses 419 MB of RAM at idle*" but so what? Almost no-one uses a *bare* system without adding apps..

Comment: (quote in last comment was from https://debugpointnews.com/lubuntu-24-04-snap/) as what we use the box influences what space is required to install, but also free space required to update it (*with more space needed if you don't do it often & regularly*).   I still use devices on occasion with only 1GB of RAM, but I use them very differently to my usual higher-spec'd devices. In deciding what I'd use though; I'd consider more than just hardware, in particular what apps you'll use, how it'll be used (*including the future; months? years?*) which are details you didn't include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 16 gb internal storage, none of the supported versions of regular Ubuntu will work, as Ubuntu installation will consume almost all of the disk space. Afterwards, you will not be able to install any programs due to lack of space.

Instead, get a fast MicroSD card (64 GB or 128 GB), and use it as your primary boot device.

As the computer is old and not very powerful, lightweight flavors like Lubuntu and Xubuntu would be much more responsive than regular Ubuntu. Also, their default installations consume significantly less disk space than regular Ubuntu. You can use the latest LTS version for longer support.

Also, if you use APT packages instead of snap packages (e.g. see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401) answer for Firefox), they will consume less disk space and the computer will open programs relatively faster.

Comment: Thanks , I installed window 10 lite which is modified by someone remove lots of optional features which consume storge , now it's working properly and i am using vs code,Rstudio with different frameorks:)